# Nintex Forms 2013 for SharePoint

Tags: 2013, form, nintex

I am pretty new to SharePoint and couldn't find answer anywhere so:

I have taken over SharePoint for a colleague that has left the company.

We have multiple SharePoint 2013 site collections and on each of those in Site Features "Nintex Workflow 2013" is activated.

On one of these sites, while editing a list I have "Nintex Forms" in the Customize List section and we need this button on other sites.

[image: Nintex Forms Button]

**How do I activate the Nintex Forms button in lists on other site collections?**

There is no "Nintex Forms 2013" in Site features, only "Nintex Workflow 2013" but even though that's the case, on the first site I have the "Nintex Forms" button, so the feature must be somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to activate the features at site collection level and then at the site level.

Following documentations will guide you step by step to activate Nintex forms in SharePoint:

1. [Activate features in SharePoint](https://help.nintex.com/en-us/nintex2013/installation/InstallGuide/Activate%20features.htm).
2. [Activate Nintex Forms](https://help.nintex.com/en-US/nintex2016/sp2016/Forms/NFAdministration/Admin.ActivatingNF.htm).

Comment: It seems like I have yet to be added to site collection administators to do that.
Thanks for the help!